# I cannot find updater option on Acrobat Reader DC preferences

Tags: windows-10, adobe-reader-dc

I have lost this feature on Acrobat Reader DC

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not lose it. Adobe has removed Update Control from its free Product. It updates automatically.

The subscription product (Acrobat DC) retains the Update Option.

I have both Reader DC (one machine) and Acrobat Pro DC (other machine) and that is how it works.

Adobe Reader works fine, so we just adapt to the automatic updating.